# Fundamental Surfaces in a 3-manifold

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, combinatorial-geometry

Given a 3-manifold $M$ with a triangulation $T$, will every essential surface in $M$ be a fundamental one? If not, then what are the conditions on $T$ so that these essential surfaces become fundamental?

Comment: You cross posted this question on Math Overflow a mere 1 hour 20 minutes after posting it here. Please do not do that. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280992/fundamental-surfaces-in-3-manifolds